# How do I use a minimization function in python with constraints?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, pulp

I am trying to learn optimization with python and I am struggling quite a bit. I am hoping someone can help me understand the following problem.

Lets say I have the following data:

| truck_number | item | qty | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 | 2 | location1 |
| 2 | item1 | 3 | location2 |
| 2 | item2 | 3 | location1 |
| 3 | item3 | 2 | location2 |
| 3 | item2 | 2 | location3 |
| 4 | item1 | 3 | location2 |
| 4 | item3 | 2 | location3 |
| 5 | item2 | 5 | location3 |
| 5 | item1 | 5 | location2 |

The goal is to pair items / locations whenever possible to minimize the number of stops the truck has to make by pairing like items together.

`Number of stops = Unique locations for a truck number.`

For example a stop can be saved if `item1` going to `location1` on `truck_number 1` is moved to `truck_number 2` and `item1` on `truck_number 2` is moved to `truck_number 1`. This would save one stop. This is because both trucks are now only going to one location.

**Constraints**

One of the constraints is that the item must have enough to service that location. The total number available for each item / location is listed as dictionary below. For example `item1` only has 10 units available to go to `location1`.

```py
availability = {('item1', 'location1'): 15,
 ('item1', 'location2'): 28,
 ('item1', 'location3'): 18,
 ('item2', 'location1'): 10,
 ('item2', 'location2'): 28,
 ('item2', 'location3'): 12,
 ('item3', 'location1'): 8,
 ('item3', 'location2'): 10,
 ('item3', 'location3'): 12
}
```

The other constraint is that if an item is on a truck, then the only thing that can change is the location it is going to.

For example `truck number 2` has items `[1,2]` going to locations `[2,1]` `truck_number 2` must have items [1,2] on it after shifting item / location combinations. Like stated before, the ideal scenario would have `truck number 1` and `truck number two` switch `item 1` because `truck number 2` would then be going to the same location, `location 1`. This is ok because `item1` has enough available to serve `location1` (15 total units).

I am confused on how to set up a problem like this with dynamic constraints. Would anyone be able to help break down the problem?

**Goal and Sample Solution**

The ending output should be the optimal truck / item / location combination.

A sample output after optimizing for the first two truck numbers might look like this:

| truck_number | item | qty | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 | 2 | location2 |
| 2 | item1 | 3 | location1 |
| 2 | item2 | 3 | location1 |

`truck_number_2` and `truck_number_1` switched `item1` to allow `truck_number_2` to go to the same location. The goal would be to reallocate all items on trucks to minimize the number of locations each truck has to go to, while checking to make sure there is enough of the item at the location in the `availability` dictionary.

Comment: This isn't really an "entry level" problem, but if you wish to pursue...  Think about what the main decision variable represents from the language of the problem.  This will help you figure out which sets/indices are important.  Then think about how to construct simple equations to express the necessary expressions that you stated, in English, then in "math."  Put some work into it and edit your post if you get stuck.  Main/big hint:  I think I would use a decision variable (indexed appropriately) to show the quantity of item x moved from truck y to truck z ...

Comment: Thank you for the hint, appreciate the guidance!

Comment: Need some clarification on the constraints. For the first constraint, you mean that the total number of a certain item should be equal or greater than that amount, correct, e.g. location1 should have at least 10 item1s across all trucks. For the second constraint, shouldn't `truck_number 2` should have 6 items total. Finally, are the listed quantities fixed to each item?

Comment: I have made some edits to hopefully make the constraints more clear.

Comment: Re-reading, it seems like you mean that item-location pairs are fixed, item-truck pairs are fixed, but item-location-truck triples are variable.

Comment: Yeah, I used to think I understood the problem...  It isn't real clear what the variables are.  I thought that moving things between trucks was the game, now I'm not sure... and it isn't clear what is going on with the quantity limits.  Lars, you might need to edit this for clarity and provide a sample solution that addresses some of this, including how changing assignments squares up with the supply quantity and the demands, etc.

Comment: Added some more context and a sample solution, hopefully this will make it a little clearer. I have realized that this problem is much more difficult than I had originally anticipated.

Comment: No offense, but... this is still an incomprehensible explanation of the problem with several confusing/contradictory statements.  You say that a constraint is that things cannot be moved off of a truck, only destination change, then you move items??  Your move between trucks 1 & 2 is confusing as it does not have the same quantities as original, specifically 3 of item 1 going to location 2.  Why wouldn't you just move (if it is legal) one of item1 onto truck one and send it to location 2, which would be movement of just one item and then the quantities per destination would be same as orig.

Comment: Lastly, it is totally unclear what the items/location dictionary does if all the items are on the trucks and getting shuffled, what are these items?  And you say 10 items for location 1 of type item1 and that is not what's in the dictionary.  Suggest:  delete all and re-explain what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do a lot of guessing to come up with this, given how astonishingly poor your description remains. I ignore your *A sample output after optimizing for the first two truck numbers might look like this* because it's internally inconsistent in terms of quantity. I also ignore quantity entirely, since you seem to imply that location-item-quantity triples are immutable; that means there's no sense in applying location-item-quantity constraints.

```py
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

with StringIO('''truck  item    quantity    location
1   item1   2   location1
2   item1   3   location2
2   item2   3   location1
3   item3   2   location2
3   item2   2   location3
4   item1   3   location2
4   item3   2   location3
5   item2   5   location3
5   item1   5   location2
''') as f:
    orders = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')

"""
Minimize the number of unique locations per truck.
Truck-item pairs are fixed and unique.
Item-quantity-location triples ("orders") are fixed and non-unique.
Assignment of orders to truck-item pairs is variable.

Quantity sum per location must be less than or equal to availability. Since item-location
assignments never change, this has no effect on the optimisation and is ignored.

Decision variables:
Truck-location sums (optimised)
Truck-location assignments (non-optimised)
Order-truck assignments (non-optimised)
"""

n_orders = len(orders)
trucks = orders.truck.unique()
n_trucks = len(trucks)
locations = orders.location.unique()
n_locations = len(locations)
items = orders.item.unique()
n_items = len(items)
n_location_costs = n_trucks * n_locations
n_assignments = n_trucks * n_orders

c = np.empty(n_trucks + n_location_costs + n_assignments, dtype=int)
c[:n_trucks] = 1  # truck location sums are minimized
c[n_trucks:] = 0  # nothing else is

# All decision variables: truck location sums, truck location assignments and truck order assignment are integral
integrality = np.ones(n_trucks + n_location_costs + n_assignments, dtype=int)

lower = np.empty_like(c)
lower[:n_trucks] = 1                            # Every truck has at least one location
lower[n_trucks: n_trucks+n_location_costs] = 0  # Truck-location assignments might not exist
lower[-n_assignments:] = 0                      # Every potential truck-order assignment might not exist
upper = np.empty_like(c)
upper[:n_trucks] = n_locations                  # Every truck can have at most all locations
upper[n_trucks: n_trucks+n_location_costs] = 1  # Truck-location assignments might exist
upper[-n_assignments:] = 1                      # Every potential truck-order assignment might exist

# Truck location sum = sum of truck-location assignments
# 0 = -(truck_locations) + sum(truck_location_assignments)
lb_truck_location = ub_truck_location = np.zeros(n_trucks, dtype=int)
A_truck_location = np.hstack((
    -np.eye(n_trucks, dtype=int),                             # -(truck_locations)
    np.eye(n_trucks, dtype=int).repeat(n_locations, axis=1),  # sum(truck_location_assignments)
    np.zeros((n_trucks, n_assignments), dtype=int),           # order assignments N/A
))

# truck-location assignment is 1 if there is at least one order assignment for that truck-location pair
# That means: truck_location_assignment >= order_assignments / (1 + max_possible_orders)
# 0 <= (truck_location_assignment)(1 + max_possible_orders) - sum(order_assignments)
order_matches_location = np.equal.outer(locations, orders.location.values).astype(int)  # 2D array: is the given order column for this location row?
order_kronecker = np.kron(np.eye(n_trucks, dtype=int), order_matches_location)          # Kronecker-tile all truck-order assignments by location
lb_location_cost_bottom = np.zeros(n_location_costs, dtype=int)
ub_location_cost_bottom = np.full(shape=n_location_costs, fill_value=np.inf)
A_location_cost_bottom = np.hstack((
    np.zeros((n_location_costs, n_trucks), dtype=int),   # Truck-location sums N/A
    np.eye(n_location_costs, dtype=int)*(1 + n_orders),  # (truck_location_assignment)(1 + max_possible_orders)
    -order_kronecker,                                    # -sum(order_assignments)
))

# Truck-location assignments also have an upper limit: truck_location_assignment <= sum(order_assignments)
# sum(order_assignments) - truck_location_assignment >= 0
lb_location_cost_top = lb_location_cost_bottom
ub_location_cost_top = np.full(n_location_costs, np.inf)
A_location_cost_top = np.hstack((
    np.zeros((n_location_costs, n_trucks), dtype=int),  # Truck-location sums N/A
    -np.eye(n_location_costs, dtype=int),               # -truck_location_assignment
    order_kronecker,                                    # sum(order_assignments)
))

# Order assignments must have a unique (1:1) mapping to trucks
lb_unique_order = ub_unique_order = np.ones(n_orders, dtype=int)
A_unique_order = np.hstack((
    np.zeros((n_orders, n_trucks), dtype=int),           # Truck-location sums N/A
    np.zeros((n_orders, n_location_costs), dtype=int),   # Truck-location assignments N/A
    np.tile(np.eye(n_orders, dtype=int), (1, n_trucks))  # All order assignments for each truck
))

# The presence of an item type (regardless of quantity or location) on a truck must not change
order_matches_item = np.equal.outer(items, orders.item.values).astype(int)
initial_trucks = np.equal.outer(trucks, orders.truck.values).astype(int)
truck_items = order_matches_item @ initial_trucks.T
item_kronecker = np.kron(np.eye(n_trucks, dtype=int), order_matches_item)
initial_kronecker = item_kronecker[truck_items.T.ravel().astype(bool), :]
kn = initial_kronecker.shape[0]
lb_truck_item = np.ones(kn, dtype=int)
ub_truck_item = np.full(kn, np.inf)
A_truck_item = np.hstack((
    np.zeros((kn, n_trucks), dtype=int),
    np.zeros((kn, n_location_costs), dtype=int),
    initial_kronecker,
))


all_lb = np.concatenate((lb_truck_location, lb_location_cost_bottom, lb_location_cost_top, lb_unique_order, lb_truck_item))
all_ub = np.concatenate((ub_truck_location, ub_location_cost_bottom, ub_location_cost_top, ub_unique_order, ub_truck_item))
all_A =  np.vstack     (( A_truck_location,  A_location_cost_bottom,  A_location_cost_top,  A_unique_order,  A_truck_item))
result = milp(
    c=c, integrality=integrality, bounds=Bounds(lb=lower, ub=upper),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(lb=all_lb, A=all_A, ub=all_ub),
)

print(result.message)
assert result.success

truck_location_sums = result.x[:n_trucks]
truck_location_assignments = result.x[n_trucks: n_trucks+n_location_costs].reshape((n_trucks, -1))
truck_order_assignments = result.x[-n_assignments:].reshape((n_trucks, -1))

print('Locations per truck:')
print(truck_location_sums.astype(int))
print()

print('Truck-location assignments:')
print(truck_location_assignments.astype(int))
print()

print('Truck-order assignments:')
print(truck_order_assignments.astype(int))
orders['new_truck'] = np.broadcast_to(trucks, (n_orders, n_trucks))[truck_order_assignments.astype(bool).T]
print(orders)
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
Locations per truck:
[1 1 1 1 2]

Truck-location assignments:
[[0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]]

Truck-order assignments:
[[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]]
   truck   item  quantity   location  new_truck
0      1  item1         2  location1          2
1      2  item1         3  location2          1
2      2  item2         3  location1          2
3      3  item3         2  location2          4
4      3  item2         2  location3          3
5      4  item1         3  location2          5
6      4  item3         2  location3          3
7      5  item2         5  location3          5
8      5  item1         5  location2          4
```